# Latest Solaris 10 patch that supports java 1.5

Tags: java, solaris

We have Java 1.5 application running on Solaris 10/08 operating system update. We are currently planning to upgrade the Solaris 10 to latest patch level. But most recent patch of Solaris 10 doesn't support JDK 1.5 so want to know what is the most latest Solaris 10 patch that can support Java 1.5.

Comment: What do you mean by "support"?  Java 1.5 is officially supported by Oracle on that version of Solaris, or that Java 1.5 works?  Official extended support for Java 1.5 ended in May 2015, so Java 1.5 isn't officially supported in any manner anyway.  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I would be interested in knowing the latest solaris 10 patch on which Java 1.5 works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The lastest Patches for Solaris 10 with Java 1.5 is update 85.

SPARC:

```
118666-86  JavaSE 5.0: update 85 patch (equivalent to JDK 5.0u85) Solaris SRARC (32bit)
118667-86  JavaSE 5.0: update 85 patch (equivalent to JDK 5.0u85), Solaris SRARC 64bit
```

x86:

```
118668-86  JavaSE 5.0: update 85 patch (equivalent to JDK 5.0u85)  Solaris x86 (32bit)
118669-86  JavaSE 5.0: update 85 patch (equivalent to JDK 5.0u85), Solaris x86_64 (64bit)
```

Oracle cross-platform (for all available OS) patch number for support.oracle.com is:

```
20418696
```